# Iron or steel melting in ancient time

Tags: iron-age

How did people from the ancient world, like Warring States period China, melt a high temperature metal like iron when the high temp crucible was not even invented nor having a fire source hot enough to melt them?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on [Ferrous metallurgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous_metallurgy)?

Comment: Also see [Wootz Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wootz_steel)